# ACPI Throttling in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, speed, acpi, throttling

I'm looking to throttle my cpu through the ACPI. I've read up on it, but I keep receiving permission denied statements. I have 8 available throttling states. Here are the outcomes of my atttempts:

> evan@evan-laptop:/proc/acpi/processor/CPU0$ echo 3 > /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/throttling
>
> bash: /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/throttling: Permission denied
>
> evan@evan-laptop:/proc/acpi/processor/CPU0$ sudo echo 3 > /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/throttling
>
> bash: /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/throttling: Permission denied

EDIT: For reference, I am running Ubuntu Karmic with Intel Core Duo T2500 with ACPI enabled

Comment: If you want to control it from terminal then also add info about your computer. It could be useful. `uname -a`, `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do

```
cat /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/throttling
```

Then use any of those states:

```
echo T4 > /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/throttling
```

Also you can look in `cat info` if throttling is enabled.

Comment: Nope, not weird just more specific needs...

Comment: hmmm, thanks for looking into this. I had tried this too and tried again, but I get the same Permission Denied line. This is my first computer with Linux, so I'll search around for a little bit.

Comment: egon, I found out that the sudo only applies to the echo rather than the whole statement. if I just run it as a script from sudo or su to root (is there root on Ubuntu?) The problem is solved. It was definitely my newness to Linux that caused this particular problem

Comment: totally forgot about that... I was logged in as root... so yeah... :D

Comment: `>` cannot be used with `sudo`, `tee` can. just do `echo T4 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/throttling`